# How can I make a layer "blend" into an existing picture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, distortion

I am trying to insert a cropped out part of one picture into another picture.

I am copying over a layer, but my issue is that the target picture is a little grainy.  The layer lines up perfectly from a perspective point of view, but it stands out like a sore thumb because the layer is much more clear compared to the picture that it's sitting on top of.

Is there any way I can take a layer and make it easier to blend in with a background image?

Here is a part of the background to show the grainyness of the picture:

[image: Grainy screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the other image it's a little hard to say just exactly what has to be done to get them both into the same ballpark, but you're probably going to have to "degrade" your cropped image a bit. Experiment (on a copy) with some or all of these procedures:

Add noise.

Try a bit of blurring.

Feather the edges of the cropped image a few pixels.

Try getting the colors of the cropped image to match the background image more closely with the Match Color tool (Image > Adjustments > Match Color). (I think that's where it is; I'm doing this from memory.)

That's about all I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: I would also try the different blend modes in the "layers" screen. Maybe try the heal brush on the edges?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may want to look at is using [Layer Masks](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layer-masks/) with some [Smart Filters](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/smart-filters/apply_smart_filters.php). The layer masks will enable you to hide the really bad parts of the top image and apply soft blending as necessarily. The Smart Filters will allow you to apply just the right amount of blur to eliminate the grain.  These two very important elements of Photoshop can be a little intimidating at first, but both are worth techniques are worth learning.